# HTML разметка для БЭМ блока

Tags: html, вёрстка, бэм

В БЭМ методологии написано:

> HTML разметка блока повторяется каждый раз, когда блок встречается на странице.

То есть, получается, что так делать нельзя?

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menu__logo></div>
    <a class="menu__link></a>
</div>
<div class="menu">
    <button class="menu__exit-button></button>
</div>
```

Ведь у одного и того же блока разная разметка

Answer (score 0):

БЭМ - Блок-Элемент-Модификатор
У вас повторяется название блока - "menu", блок должен быть уникальным.